# Question about Topological Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, dimension-theory-analysis

Suppose we have a topological manifold $M$ so by definition we have that,
(1) $M$ is Hausdorff
(2) $M$ is second countable
(3) $M$ is locally euclidean

I have a question but I don't know if it is the right question or the wrong question
so question is since $M$ is locally euclidean that is for all $p\in M$ there exists an open set $p\in U$ and a map $\phi:U\to \mathbb{R^n}$ which is homeomorphism.And then $n$ will be the dimension of $M$ and $(U,\phi)$ as a chart, can we say anything about for n-dimensional manifold we need a minimum $m$ number of charts to cover the whole manifold.Is this a valid question? or there can be a manifolds which always need infinite number of charts?

Comment: Without a connectedness hypothesis, you have an obvious counterexample: just put a bunch of spheres next to each other. (Even if we assume connectedness we can get a counterexample, namely an infinite-genus manifold, but it takes a bit more thought to see that this actually can't be covered "efficiently.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do you have a reference for the infinite genus surface? I agree that this won't work if the charts are simply connected, but what about two charts with infinitely many holes (similarly to the fact that two annuli can cover the torus)?

Comment: You did not specify what you mean by a "chart." The answer will depend on the precise definition.

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags. There is no multivariable calculus, manifold with boundary, or smooth structure (hence no differential geometry) here.

Comment: One can cover the infinite genus surface which is an infinite chain of tori glued together with two charts, no?

Comment: (by the way, there are uncountably many different — up to homeo — surfaces of infinite genus, so there is no «*the* infinite genus surface» You can construct many from a regular, infinite tree of degree $3$: pick an infinite connected subtree, make the edges thick, and take the boundary. The surfaces you get usually have different spaces of ends)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That was my -sort of- idea for the infinite chain of torus. But you are right, many other infinite genus surfaces exist.